# Sql Case statement from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case

**I cant get the case statement to run correctly**
**Here is the question**
3. From the City table select name. From the Country table select Name. Create a calculated field 'GNPOverPop' that calculates GNP/City Population and format that field with 6 decimal places. Then create another calculated field that determines the following:

If the city has a population that is:

greater than or equal to 10% of the countries population then prints '10% or more' into the calculated field value

greater than or equal to 5% of the countries population then prints '5% or more' into the calculated field value

greater than or equal to 1% of the countries population then prints '1% or more' into the calculated field value

not in one of the above categories then prints 'Less than 1%' into the calculated field value

Order the results in the following manner:

First by GNPOver Pop in descending order
Second by Country Name
Third by City Name

Your results will look like the following:

```
+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+-------------------+

| Name                              | name                                  | GNPOverPop | PopPercentageDesc |

+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+-------------------+

| Charleston                        | United States                         | 95.558200  | .1% or more       |

| Carson                            | United States                         | 95.530312  | .1% or more       |

| Odessa                            | United States                         | 95.312063  | .1% or more       |

| Elgin                             | United States                         | 95.189469  | .1% or more       |

| Kenosha                           | United States                         | 95.147965  | .1% or more       |

| Fall River                        | United States                         | 93.983767  | .1% or more       |

| Santa Monica                      | United States                         | 93.437925  | .1% or more       |

| Cary                              | United States                         | 93.305779  | .1% or more       |

| Boulder                           | United States                         | 93.280212  | .1% or more       |

| Visalia                           | United States                         | 92.747543  | .1% or more       |

| San Mateo                         | United States                         | 92.710160  | .1% or more       |

| Arden-Arcade                      | United States                         | 92.467405  | .1% or more       |

| Fairfield                         | United States                         | 92.250911  | .1% or more       |

| Gainesville                       | United States                         | 92.215926  | .1% or more       |

| Compton                           | United States                         | 91.646925  | .1% or more       |

| Billings                          | United States                         | 91.524713  | .1% or more       |

| Roanoke                           | United States                         | 91.162955  | .1% or more       |

| Brockton                          | United States                         | 90.874825  | .1% or more       |
```

**Here is my query**

```
SELECT City.name, Country.Name, FORMAT((Country.GNP/City.Population),6) AS 
'GNPOverPop', 
case Country.Population 
WHEN City.Population>=0.1 THEN '10% OR MORE' 
WHEN City.Population>=0.05 THEN '5% OR MORE' 
WHEN City.Population>=0.01 THEN '1% OR MORE' 
ELSE 'Less than 1%' END AS 'PopPercentageDesc' 
FROM City JOIN Country ON City.Country = Country.Code 
ORDER BY GNPOverPop DESC, Country.Name, City.name
```

**My results of the case statement is only returning the else "Less then 1%" for everything. Thanks in advance. **

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query I ran and the behaviour is what is expected.

Query:

```
create table city (name varchar(20),popula decimal (5,2), GNP decimal(5,2))
  insert into city 
  values
  ('HYD',0.1,100),
  ('BOM',0.06,30),
  ('CHN',0.02,40),
  ('DEL' ,0.2,50);


  select name,case when popula >= 0.1 then '10% or more'
    when popula >= 0.05 and popula < 0.1 then '5% or more'
    when popula >= 0.01 and popula <0.05 then '1% or more'
    else 'less than 1%' end as PopPercentageDESC
  from city
```

Output:

```
name    PopPercentageDESC
HYD    10% or more
BOM    5% or more
CHN    1% or more
DEL    10% or more
```